# JavaScript Nativescript: Make ListView height equal to total height of rows

Tags: javascript, android, listview, nativescript

### Context

I have a `listView` element that pulls in its elements via external source. As such I can't be sure how many rows there will be.

I therefore set the `listView` attribute `height` to a bound variable, and the attribute `rowHeight` to a constant.

However, if I multiply multiply the `rowHeight` by the number of list items, the height of the `listView` is always too much and leaves empty space.

### Code

*`page.xml`*

```
<StackLayout class="group-meta-active" visibility="{{ userCanSelect ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}" ontap="teamSelect">
    <Label text="Selection" class="group-meta-active-team-label" />
    <Label text="{{ selectionName || '' }}" id="{{ selectionId || 0 }}" visibility="{{ selectionId ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'}}" class="group-meta-active-team-name" />
    <Label text="Tap To Decide" visibility="{{ selectionId ? 'collapsed' : 'visible'}}" class="group-meta-active-team-decide" />
    <ListView items="{{ userAllowedSelections }}" height="{{ userSelectionHeight }}" class="list-clubs" itemTap="selectTeam" rowHeight="35" visibility="{{ selectionSelect ? 'visible' : 'collapsed' }}">
        <ListView.itemTemplate>
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="list-clubs-cont">
                <Label text="{{ clubName || 'Loading...' }}" textWrap="false" class="list-clubs-label" />
                <Label text="vs" textWrap="false" class="list-clubs-vs" />
                <Label text="{{ clubOpponent || 'Loading...' }}" textWrap="false" class="list-clubs-opp" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ListView.itemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

*`page.js`*

```
//When setting page variables; e is the retrieved object;
//e.allowedSelections is an array
pageData.set("userAllowedSelections", (e.allowedSelections));
pageData.set("userSelectionHeight", (e.allowedSelections.length * 35));
```

### Output Images

- [Top of list element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpPMI.png)
- [Bottom of list element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLTMX.png)

### Question

As you can see, the `listView` element is a few pixels taller than the elements inside, despite the `rowHeight` being set to 35, and the `listView` `height` attribute set to 35 x `listView` element array length.

I have tried:

- Setting the multiplication to one-off (e.g. 34/36)
- Setting the multiplication to a half-value (e.g. 34.5, 35.5)
- Mixing and matching with multiple values
- Removing all padding and margins on the list items (the only CSS now is font styling and `vertical-align: middle`

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking of two possible reasons for this to happen.

- Using DP (a.k.a device independent pixels) in NativeScript is implemented by calculating the actual pixel for the current device and the actual device density.This might lead to a different result when using hard coded values as the density of different devices varies and those calculations might need some rounding.
- the separator width (approx. 1dp or less)

Using your code base this solution is perfect on API19 and about half pixel off in API23 (for each)

```
var size = (e.allowedSelections.length * 35) + (e.allowedSelections.length * 0.9);
pageData.set("userSelectionHeight", size);
```

Still, you can check the current device screen scale and dimensions and make better calculation for each device using the platform module

```
import { screen, ScreenMetrics } from "platform";
var mainScreen = screen.mainScreen;
console.log(mainScreen.heightDIPs);
console.log(mainScreen.heightPixels);
console.log(mainScreen.scale);
console.log(mainScreen.widthDIPs);
console.log(mainScreen.widthPixels);
```